# Updating Cloudfront Tags using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform to create AWS Cloudfront Resource. The tags to set on the resource is already defined in a variables file. After creation/During Creation I want to add a new key to the tags with the key as Distribution-ID and value as ID of the distribution to be created. I am not getting any solution for doing the same. Any suggestion, or if my approach is not proper.

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "testing-cf" {
    enabled = true
    aliases = var.cf-user-origin.aliases
    origin {
        domain_name = var.cf-user-origin.target_origin_id
        origin_id   = "cf-user-prod"
    }
    default_cache_behavior {
        allowed_methods  = var.cf-user-origin.allowed_methods
        cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
        target_origin_id = "cf-user-prod"
        max_ttl =  0
        min_ttl = 0
        viewer_protocol_policy = "allow-all"
        
    }
    tags = var.cf-prod-tags

    viewer_certificate {
        acm_certificate_arn = var.cf-user-origin.acm_certificate_arn
        cloudfront_default_certificate = false
        minimum_protocol_version = var.cf-user-origin.minimum_protocol_version
    }
    restrictions {
        geo_restriction {
            locations = []
            restriction_type = "none"
        }  
    }
}
```

The contents of Variables file is a follows:

```
variable "cf-prod-tags" {
    type = map
    default = {
        "Team" = "cf"
        "Environment" = "PROD"        
    }
}

variable "cf-user-origin" {
    type = any
    default = {
        acm_certificate_arn = "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:12345678:certificate/1234-5678-999-39f6f6"
        target_origin_id = "test.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
        aliases = ["cf-lb-testing.in"]
        allowed_methods = ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT"]
        minimum_protocol_version = "TLSv1.2_2021"
    }
}
```

Comment: The distribution ID of the same CF distribution you are creating?

Comment: yes, the same Distribution ID

Comment: That is not possible. Self referencing exists only for provisioners IIRC.

Comment: Is there any way we can update the tags of the CF we created. As I was unable to find any way to do it either.

Comment: Not sure why you would need the distribution ID as a tag when in order to get to the distribution you have to see its ID.

Comment: For some of our other internal use cases we need to add ID as tag

Comment: Both @MarkoE comments are very salient here; especially the latter when the ID is available as an exported resource attribute, and therefore adding it as a tag is redundant.

Comment: For our internal use cases we use ID as tag, like in cost explorer we use Distribution-ID tag as a way to find the cost of CF distributions.